# Preact.js How to create hierarchical component

Tags: javascript, preact

I want to create a component as parents that generate HTML container, and some another components as children.
for example i have CardComponent like this

```
import { h, Component } from "preact"

    class CardComponent extends Component{
        render(){
            return (
                <div className='card'>

                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

and let say we have ButtonComponent
import { h, Component } from "preact"

```
class ButtonComponent extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <button>
              a button
            </button>
        )
    }
}
```

then i want to call these component like this

```
<CardComponent>
    <ButtonComponent/>
</CardComponent>
```

what should i do on my `CardComponent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do:

```
import { h, Component } from "preact"

    class CardComponent extends Component{
        render(){
            return (
                <div className='card'>
                  {this.props.children}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```